# Code Delphi to C# byte

Tags: c#, delphi

I need help with this code in Delphi:

```pascal
function say(mensagem: string):string; 
var 
  H: HWND; 
  letra: Integer; 
  B: Byte; 
begin 
  H := FindWindow(nil, 'tibia'); 
  for letra := 1 to Length(mensagem) do 
  begin 
    B := Byte(mensagem[letra]); 
    SendMessage(H, WM_CHAR, B, 0); 
  end; 
  SendMessage(H, WM_CHAR, 13, 0); 
end;
```

To C#:

```
public void say(string message)
{
  int letra;
  IntPtr hWnd = FindWindow("TibiaClient", null);
  for (letra = 1; letra <= message.Length; letra++)
  { 
    Byte B = Convert.ToByte(message[letra]);
    SendMessage(hWnd, WM_CHAR, B, 0);
    SendMessage(hWnd, WM_CHAR, 13, 0);
  }
}
```

Error in:  `Byte B = Convert.ToByte(message[letra]);`

Comment: There is little that's more frustrating than someone: asking for help, saying they "Get an error", but ***not bothering*** to explain the error either with an exact message or statement of expected behaviour vs actual behaviour. It's quite rude and inconsiderate towards the people you're approaching for help.

Answer (score 0):

Your Delphi code assumes 8 bit text encoding. So in C# you need to use the equivalent encoding to encode the text to bytes, and then send to the other window. You'd write it like this:

```
foreach (byte b in Encoding.Default.GetBytes(message))
{
    SendMessage(hWnd, WM_CHAR, b, 0);
}
SendMessage(hWnd, WM_CHAR, 13, 0);
```

Note also that:

- I moved the sending of the enter key outside the loop, to match the Delphi code.
- The call to `FindWindow` differs between the two versions.

Comment: That information is contained on MSDN. Rather than me telling you, how about I show you how to find it for yourself. Then you'll never need to ask that question again? Search for "Encoding MSDN". Follow the hit that looks like it leads to MSDN class docs. Near the top of the page, read the namespace and assembly fields which tell you what to use and what reference to add. In this case, you won't need to add a reference, your project will already reference the assembly.

Comment: How to i change this SendMessage to delete? i need to change WM_CHAR or "13" ?
Sorry for first comment, noob of my part.

Comment: I don't really understand that question. I don't see anything that suggests this code is trying to delete anything. I thought I answered the question that you asked. What did I miss?

Comment: I would suggest though that you read up on virtual key codes and WM_CHAR and so learn what virtual key code 13 is.